# Trouble with build.js for javascript compressing in requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Here is my `require.js` project:

```
Project
|
|--lib
|--src
    |--util.js
|--app.js
|--build.js
|--main.js
|--index.html
```

Here is my `main.js`:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "./src"
});

require(["util"], function (Util) {

});
```

And here is my `build.js`

```
({
    name: "main",
    out: "main-built.js"
})
```

When I want use `r.js` to build, I want see error:

> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'project\util.js`

I think this means the `build.js` doesn't read the `main.js`'s config, so it can't find `project/src/util.js` but try to find `project/util.js`

How can I change the `build.js` to make it right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `mainConfigFile` to tell `r.js` that your runtime configuration is in your `main.js` file.

```
({
    mainConfigFile: "main.js"
    name: "main",
    out: "main-built.js"
})
```

Even if your configuration is in your `main` module, `r.js` is not going to *interpret* the configuration in the file unless you tell it explicitly to fetch it from there with `mainConfigFile`.